# How to map BigInteger in Hibernate to DB2

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, biginteger

I've got a class that is generated through JAXB that I am trying to use as an entity in Hibernate. There are numeric fields that are defined as Java BigIntegers. No matter what I define the column as in DB2, Hibernate complains with some variation of:

Wrong column type .... for column MY_COLUMN Found: decimal, expected: numeric(19,2).

I've tried DB2 bigints, I've tried numeric (19,2), etc.

I am letting Hibernate choose the dialect. It is choosing the DB2 dialect. How can I define the column in DB2 so that Hibernate will allow me to use it to store a Java BigInteger?

If I define it as a big_integer in Hibernate, and as a bigint in DB2, I get:

Wrong column type .... for column MY_COLUMN Found: bigint, expected: numeric(19,2)

**UPDATE**

So I changed hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto from validate to create and let Hibernate create the schema itself. From the log I could see that is was generating the create table statement using a definition of numeric(19,2). In DB2, once the table was created, the definition was decimal(19,2). The app started up OK.

Then I shut down the app, recompiled setting hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto back to validate, and restarted.

Hibernate errored out with:
Found: decimal, expected: numeric(19,2)

So Hibernate can't validate a schema it just created itself?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate schema creation, update and validations are aberrations that shouldn't exist. All those three features have plenty of bugs and are know to fail under several circumstances, so try to avoid it as much as you can (that's why some people specialise as database developers).

About how to store a large integer, if the column is a DB2 bigint, you can map it to a long (both are 64 bits).

If you need more than 64 bits, the column needs to be a Numeric, which allows integers up to 2^81-1. Hibernate will map this automatically to a BigDecimal or BigInteger.

If you need to store even bigger numbers (which BigInteger supports), you'll need to write your own [custom type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html) to write the number to a varchar.

As a side note, it's a **very, very, very** bad practice to mix the objects that you use to communicate with other systems (your xml object), with something you use to persist (both are different domains). And I have the feeling that might also be using the same object as part of your domain, which is BAD, evil, and it's criminal in some countries :).